# Iterate list by step in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp, slice

I have a list in Elisp. How do i return a list consisting of every nth element starting from the 1st? In Python i have slice notation:

```
>>> range(10)[::3]
[0, 3, 6, 9]
```

I can't find anything helpful in [`dash.el`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) list API, so i wrote my solution using [`loop` macro](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html):

```
(defun step (n xs)
  (loop for x in xs by (lambda (xs) (nthcdr n xs))
        collect x))

ELISP> (step 3 (number-sequence 0 10))
(0 3 6 9)
```

By the way, `(lambda (xs) (nthcdr n xs))` could be rewritten with `dash.el`'s partial application function [`-partial`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-partial-fn-rest-args): `(-partial 'nthcdr n)`.

`loop` macro seems like overkill. How do i return elements by step in Emacs Lisp?

Comment: Just use your solution with loop. In actuality it's `-partial` that is overkill, because Emacs isn't a functional language. You have to be careful with functional approach if you care about performance.

Comment: @abo-abo  No offense meant, but that's a stupid argument.  `-partial` is just an alias for `apply-partially`, which in turn just creates a `lambda`, so by all means `(-partial 'nthcdr n)` is **not any different** from `(lambda (xs) (nthcdr n xs))`, other than being shorter.  And any claim about the performance of dash.el is FUD unless backed by hard numbers.

Comment: @lunaryorn, no offense taken. Have you actually looked at the code of `apply-partially`?
It adds an unnecessary level of indirection that `loop` does not possess.
It's like virtual calls in C++: it's fine to have them most of the time,
but you don't see `std::vector` having them, do you?

Comment: @abo-abo Are you referring to the `funcall` in the lambda created by `apply-partially`?  That's not really an additional indirection:  `funcall` takes a symbol, dereferences it's function cell, and calls it.  That's more or less the same as the Emacs interpreter also does for a normal function.  To keep your C++ analogy:  In Emacs Lisp all function are virtual, so does it matter?

Comment: Double indirection applied to a cheap call, like indexing, is double cost.
And it becomes worse when you have to call it in a loop like in this case.
Compare 
`(defun add (x y) (+ x y))
(byte-compile (lambda (x) (funcall (apply-partially 'add 5))))
(byte-compile (lambda (x) (+ 5 x)))`
although `apply-partially` returns closures that aren't even
byte-compiled.

Comment: @abo-abo List indexing is `O(n)` in Emacs.  That's not cheap.   I don't think that there's any difference between `apply-partially` and `lambda` here.  Moving the function definition out of the `by` into a `let`-bound variable will make a larger difference.  But feel free to profile…

Comment: @lunaryorn, just finished profiling, `-partial` takes 60% more time.

Comment: Actually, 300% more time, for a 1..10000 as data, selecting every 3rd element, averaged on 1000 runs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`dash`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) package's [`slice`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-slice-list-from-optional-to-step) supports step from version 2.7. Therefore Python's `range(10)[1:7:2]` is equivalent to:

```
(-slice (number-sequence 0 9) 1 7 2) ; (1 3 5)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a short illustration, comparing using `-partial` and a plain lambda in a loop:

```lisp
(require 'cl-lib)

(prog1 nil
  (setq bigdata (number-sequence 1 10000)))

(defun every-nth-1 (n xs)
  (cl-loop for x in xs by (lambda (xs) (nthcdr n xs))
     collect x))

(defun every-nth-2 (n xs)
  (cl-loop for x in xs by (-partial 'nthcdr n)
     collect x))

(defmacro util-timeit (expr)
  (let ((t-beg (float-time))
        (res (dotimes (i 1000)
               (eval expr)))
        (t-end (float-time)))
    (/
     (- t-end t-beg)
     1000)))

(setq time1
      (util-timeit
       (length (every-nth-1 3 bigdata))))

(setq time2
      (util-timeit
       (every-nth-2 3 bigdata)))

(message "%s" (/ time2 time1))
```

Calling `eval-buffer` gives me a result around 4. This means that
`(lambda (xs) (nthcdr n xs))` is 4 times faster than `(-partial 'nthcdr n)`,
at least without byte compilation.

With byte-compilation, it gives an astounding 12.2-13.6 times difference in performance
in favor of a plain lambda!

Comment: Not surprised: `-partial` (and `apply-partially`) uses both `&rest` and `apply` which are fairly slow.

Comment: Can you please integrate what you discussed with @lunaryorn into the answer?

Comment: Well, the answer is the same as two days ago: don't use `-partial` in a loop.
In fact, be as primitive as possible when it comes to loops. And your `step` function looks
optimal to me.

Comment: @abo-abo, I mean it would be great if you could incorporate the your arguments from comments into this question, so that one could easily read why using `-partial` is suboptimal.